# jquery removeClass('').addClass('') needs two clicks in IE

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following jquery which when you click the link it just updates the text and class on it. It works brilliantly in Chrome but in IE you have to click the links twice for it to do anything. I'd understand if it didn't work at all, but can't work out why you'd need to click it twice!

```
  // Subscribe to topic subscribedtotopic
    $(".notsubscribedtotopic")
    .on("click", (function () {
        SubscribeUnsubscribe($(this));

    }));


    // UnSubscribe to topic subscribedtotopic
    $(".subscribedtotopic").on("click", (function () {
        SubscribeUnsubscribe($(this));
    }));


    function SubscribeUnsubscribe(link) {

        var topicid = link.attr('rel');
        link.slideUp('fast');
        if (link.attr('class') == 'notsubscribedtotopic') {
            link.html('Unsubscribe From Topic');
            link.removeClass('notsubscribedtotopic').addClass('subscribedtotopic');
            link.slideDown();

            return false;
        } else {
            link.html('Subscribe To Topic');
            link.removeClass('subscribedtotopic').addClass('notsubscribedtotopic');
            link.slideDown();

            return false;
        }

    };
```

Comment: Can you post a sample link as well so we can see the html?  Or maybe create an example in jsFiddle?

Comment: Interesting.. if I put it in jsfiddle it works!

Answer (score 0):

How about to remove "return false" ?

Comment: `return false` is to stop the link from firing.  He could have use `event.preventDefault()` to do the same (had he passed the event as an argument).

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code a bit and use `toggleClass` and `hasClass` along with `preventDefault()` to get rid of the `return false`:

```
// Subscribe to topic subscribedtotopic
    $(".notsubscribedtotopic").on("click", function (event) {
        SubscribeUnsubscribe($(this));
        event.preventDefault();
    });


    // UnSubscribe to topic subscribedtotopic
    $(".subscribedtotopic").on("click", function (event) {
        SubscribeUnsubscribe($(this));
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function SubscribeUnsubscribe(link) {

        var topicid = link.attr('rel');
        link.slideUp('fast', function(){
            if (link.hasClass('notsubscribedtotopic')) {
                link.html('Unsubscribe From Topic');
            } else {
                link.html('Subscribe To Topic');
            }

            link.toggleClass('notsubscribedtotopic').toggleClass('subscribedtotopic');
            link.slideDown();
        });
    }
```

Technically, the two event handlers can also be replaced with one if you give the link another class that doesn't change.